# Passing variable from .js to PHP and then receiving a new var back in response?

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I'm creating variables on server 1 and then sending them via post to a mySQL database on server 2 using PHP file located on server 2.

Javascript on server 1...

```
$.post( "http://www.website.com/xxx/update.php", { vote:currentVote, page:currentmatch, round:roundNumber, team1: firstTeam, team2: secondTeam });
```

PHP to receive post, located on server 2...

```
$round = $_POST['round'];
//etc...

//I then set the query and insert the data, no problem.
```

After that, and on the same PHP file, counting rows and assigning total to variable...

```
$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM {$page} WHERE 'vote' = {$team1}")) {
    $team1Count = $result->num_rows;
}
```

How can I send that updated $team1Count variable back to the original page?

Thanks!

Comment: Whoa there, you're escaping $page and $team1, right?  http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's `.post()` has a call back feature you can supply as an argument.

```
$.post( "http://www.website.com/xxx/update.php", { 
    vote:currentVote, 
    page:currentmatch, 
    round:roundNumber, 
    team1: firstTeam, 
    team2: secondTeam }, 
    function(data){
        //the call back, data contains your return from your php script
        console.log(data);
});
```

Just simply echo that variable from your php script

```
echo $team1Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo the updated variable from the php. Something like this -

```
$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM {$page} WHERE 'vote' = {$team1}")) {
    $team1Count = $result->num_rows;
    echo $team1Count;
}
```